# Avoiding a method to repeatedly add values to a map on different calls

Tags: java, spring-boot, refactoring, junit5

I have a service class that has a method :

```
@Service
class MService {
private Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();
public List<File> genMetFiles(String ver){
.
.
.
  buildMap(ver);
.
.
}
```

The buildMap function makes some API calls and populates the map variable.

Recently I encountered an issue:
I made a test class

```
class MServiceTest {
@Autowired
private MService service;
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource(...)
void testM(String ver) {
List<File> mFiles=service.geMetFiles(ver);

}
}
```

The Method source has multiple arguments. So each time the testM method is called it calls the service.genMetFiles function which calls the buildMap which populates the map variable. Since there will be multiple calls the map variable gets populated with extra values then is required. It will hold all the previous values generated.
I discovered this issue while debugging.
I was wondering if I could have coded in a way so that this issue wouldn't have occurred.

**My Thoughts:**

- One way could be that I could have written a @pre condition on the method, and also inside the method, the first line could have been the initializer line -> new HashMap<> rather than instantiating it at the top class level.
- Now since there are multiple Junit tests. I could make it so that each time a test is called it creates a new instance of service. I can probably achieve this by removing the @Autowired annotation and making an init() method annotated with @BeforeEach. But not sure how to initialize MService inside this method, as the class MService has @Autowired variables.

Any suggestions or thoughts on the above two approaches or any other ideas?

---

REPHRASING THE QUESTION FROM A DIFFERENT DIRECTION:

```
@Service
class MService {
private Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();
public List<File> genMetFiles(String ver){
.
.
.
  buildMap(ver);
.
.
}
```

Now if some other class has an Autowired variable of this Mservice class say mService.
Now if I call mService.buildMap("1.2.0") map will get populated with some values, after this if I call mService.buildMap("1.3.0") The new values will get added to the map or the size of the map will increase.
This is not what I want. Because if I call mService.someOtherMethod() the behavior will change.
This method uses a map variable. And that has data generated by call with "1.2.0" and "1.3.0".

Comment: What does _the map variable gets populated with extra values_ mean?  Based on the type, `map` cannot contain multiple values for the same key.  Also, based on the example, `buildMap()` is probably not thread safe.

Comment: You are keeping state in a singleton, which is bad unless you need it then you need to design for it (which you didn't).

Comment: @M.Deinum Could you provide some brief points on how could one design for it? For now, to solve this issue I moved the local variable instantiation inside the `buildMap` method. Not sure if that too has some cons

Comment: That doesn't solve it unless you also removed the instance variable. You should create the hashmap inside the `genMetFiles` methyod and don't use an instance variable. You should only have a local variable inside that method.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions in the comment section can be implemented to improvise your code.

> I can probably achieve this by removing the @Autowired annotation and making an init() method annotated with @BeforeEach. But not sure how to initialize MService inside this method, as the class MService has @Autowired variables.

`@InjectMocks` creates instance of the class and to initialize the other Autowired variables in the service class, `MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)` would inject the required mock variables.

```
class MServiceTest {
    @InjectMocks
    MService service;

    @Mock
    Foo foo

    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource(...)
    void testM(String ver) {
        List<File> mFiles = service.geMetFiles(ver);

    }
}
```

Hope this helps